# Laravel View not fitting in dompdf generated pdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

i'm using dompdf in laravel version 8+ and i generated a pdf successfully by first loading the view then extracting its content and saving it as a pdf file. there is only 1 table in my view which is loaded by dompdf and it is not fitting in the page.

[The pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5aoV.png)

anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: try changing "dpi" => 196 in dompdf config,

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look Like you need to update dpi in `dompdf config` file

Default `dpi` is `96`.Better to change it to `"dpi" => 196`

From dom pdf config file

```
 /**
         * Image DPI setting
         *
         * This setting determines the default DPI setting for images and fonts.  The
         * DPI may be overridden for inline images by explictly setting the
         * image's width & height style attributes (i.e. if the image's native
         * width is 600 pixels and you specify the image's width as 72 points,
         * the image will have a DPI of 600 in the rendered PDF.  The DPI of
         * background images can not be overridden and is controlled entirely
         * via this parameter.
         *
         * For the purposes of DOMPDF, pixels per inch (PPI) = dots per inch (DPI).
         * If a size in html is given as px (or without unit as image size),
         * this tells the corresponding size in pt.
         * This adjusts the relative sizes to be similar to the rendering of the
         * html page in a reference browser.
         *
         * In pdf, always 1 pt = 1/72 inch
         *
         * Rendering resolution of various browsers in px per inch:
         * Windows Firefox and Internet Explorer:
         *   SystemControl->Display properties->FontResolution: Default:96, largefonts:120, custom:?
         * Linux Firefox:
         *   about:config *resolution: Default:96
         *   (xorg screen dimension in mm and Desktop font dpi settings are ignored)
         *
         * Take care about extra font/image zoom factor of browser.
         *
         * In images, <img> size in pixel attribute, img css style, are overriding
         * the real image dimension in px for rendering.
         *
         * @var int
         */
        "dpi" => 96,
```

Ref:https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/blob/master/config/dompdf.php